# How would I parse multipart form data in rust?

Tags: networking, rust, tcp, network-programming, backend

I am creating a web app that receives files sent by a post request. The files are sent via multipart/form-data from the client. I am not sure on how to parse the data and store it into a variable. I would prefer it to not include external cargo packages as I would like it to be as lean and fast as possible, and I am working at tcp level as I believe that it would be the fastest. I am using the code from the rust docs website.

Here is my current code

```
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:1234").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        handle_connection(stream);
    }
}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buffer = [0; 1048576];
    stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();

    let get = b"POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n";

    if buffer.starts_with(get) {
        let response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";

        stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
        stream.flush().unwrap();
        println!("Request: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]));
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Comment: There is a good chance that by the time you complete a fast, secure and standard compliant form parser you'll recreate one of the existing crates.